# Time/space complexity of in-built python functions

Tags: python, function, time-complexity, built-in, space-complexity

What is the time/space complexity of split/strip/open (in-built python functions)?

Does anyone know where i can look up on the time/space complexity of these functions?

Comment: I do not know where you can find that information, but couldn't you just time the functions yourself and then plot the results on a graph and see if it is linear/parabolic/etc..?

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: @RockyLi has the exact answer to the question, don't bother with timing or anything like that unless you need an empirical result instead of a formal statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The exact answer will depend on what properties are fed into the function. The easiest way to find out would probably be to examine the source code for those functions. [The python source code can be found here.](https://github.com/python/cpython)

Lets take a look at the source for [split.](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/split.h) The code runs different loops depending on the properties. This is the loop for splitting by whitespace.

```
    while (maxcount-- > 0) {
    while (i < str_len && STRINGLIB_ISSPACE(str[i]))
        i++;
    if (i == str_len) break;
    j = i; i++;
    while (i < str_len && !STRINGLIB_ISSPACE(str[i]))
        i++;
```

In this code, the function will look at each character in the string (unless the maxcount is reached). The inner most loops will run n times for a string of size n. Time complexity is **O(n)**

[The source for strip](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/unicodeobject.c) steps through each character in the string.

```
    i = 0;
if (striptype != RIGHTSTRIP) {
    while (i < len) {
        Py_UCS4 ch = PyUnicode_READ(kind, data, i);
        if (!BLOOM(sepmask, ch))
            break;
        if (PyUnicode_FindChar(sepobj, ch, 0, seplen, 1) < 0)
            break;
        i++;
    }
}

j = len;
if (striptype != LEFTSTRIP) {
    j--;
    while (j >= i) {
        Py_UCS4 ch = PyUnicode_READ(kind, data, j);
        if (!BLOOM(sepmask, ch))
            break;
        if (PyUnicode_FindChar(sepobj, ch, 0, seplen, 1) < 0)
            break;
        j--;
    }

    j++;
}
```

This gives strip a time complexity of **O(n)**.

[The Source for open() shows no loops.](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/_pyio.py) This is what we would expect. There is nothing to loop through.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really helped me clarify the time complexity of those in built functions!