# Match everything after the 8th comma

Tags: python, regex

I'm parsing a raw log file and have to resort to regex because the comma delimiter shows up in a field.

```
20200914 01:38:16,ip-XX-YY-1-202,user,10.0.0.0,978,108421,QUERY,db,'select some random query, that has, commas in it, sometimes and not always quotes either..'
```

This is a maria DB audit log - I need to select the Database query which is everything after the 8th comma.
The output for the above example would be

```
`'select some random query, that has, commas in it, sometimes and not always quotes either..'`
```

I'm processing using pandas and `.str.extract`. I have a hacky version that matches everything before the 8th comma, but not sure how to get what's after it.

Comment: so, the result should be ``that has, commas in it, sometimes and not always quotes either..``?

Comment: You may use `^(?:[^,]*,){8}(.*)$` and find your expected output in group #1. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5OlBGX/1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way without regex is to use `str.split`:

```
s.split(",", 8)[-1]
```

Output:

```
"'select some random query, that has, commas in it, sometimes and not always quotes either.'"
```

Benchmark:

```
%timeit s.split(",", 8)[-1]

# 511 ns ± 46.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit re.search("^(?:[^,]*,){8}(.*)$", s).group(1)
# @41686d6564's comment
# 1.52 µs ± 121 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the regex posted in the comments will be ~10x faster

Comment: how sure are you? @Marat. Any tests?

Comment: @Marat Why do you think so? I don't really know Python but a `split()` function implementation is usually pretty fast in most programming languages. Its time complexity is usually `O(n)`. Edit: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55114114/8967612) confirms for Python.

Comment: usually, the less Python, the faster. `split` will create a Python list, plus 9 Python strings. `regexp` will be an equivalent of just two strings

Comment: @Marat based on a simple benchmark, `str.split` is about 3 times faster